# Need help using procmon to debug "Power surge on USB port"

Tags: usb, video, user-interface, debug, procmon

Like many others, I've seen a **power surge on usb port** error message pop up on my computer. Tried the usual fixes including replacing usb equipment and drivers. No luck.

However, I have noticed that what will almost always trigger the message is to play a video. The messages will continue to pop up until I sign out of Windows. When I log back in, the messages have stopped. Signing out is sufficient - I don't need to restart the machine to kill the messages.

That suggests the videos (Vimeo and/or youtube) are spawning a process that triggers the message.  Downloaded Procmon 3.7 from technet.microsoft.com to see what processes the video player was spawning and was immediately defeated by Procmon's UI. Before running a video, I thought I would try getting Procmon to filter the events based on when they occurred.  Fired up Procmon and it showed me everything as of 11:09:02 am. Fired up an app and found it in Procmon's display as 11:09:10....

Clicked on the filter icon, and set a Time of Day filter to Exclude everything prior to 11:09:08. I didn't bother typing the microsecond just typed hour:minute:second. No luck. Everything that had been displayed as of 11:09:02 was still displayed. Tried adding microseconds. No luck.  Tried flipping the Exclude switch to include and nothing changed. Tried a do over and closed the filter window instead of just clicking apply. No luck. Tried reading the help file that came  with the procmon download but it's blank.

What am I missing on how to set a time filter? What seems to be a trivial task has eluded me.

Comment: Sometimes the forest can become trees and the rabbit hole just gets deeper .. Procmon won't be able to tell you specifically what's causing the USB power surge ([USBView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560019%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might help though), and video usually works by writing directly to the screen device, so ProcMon wouldn't necessarily show you any of that either .. If you get a power surge on your USB ports while playing video, check out your video drivers and/or try using VGA, some use USB for the Audio even though it's internal so it could be your card

Comment: What are the system specs?

Comment: @txtechhelp My plan was to open procmon, open a video, when the bug fires close the browser which ostensibly would remove all browser-associated processes and then ask procmon which processes were active that weren't before the video ran. I'd then iterate on each process killing them to find the process that was sparking the bug.  All that depended on being able to filter procmon data.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to get at that YouTube/Vimeo use Flash or HTML5 for the videos since you stated `That suggests the videos (Vimeo and/or youtube) are spawning a process that triggers the message.`. So the only process that actually runs is your browser; an external 'plugin' process might run separate from the browser, but using ProcMon wouldn't necessarily show you what you're actually hunting for. However, if you remove all filters from ProcMon, you can see all system messages and sift through the data for the specific error .. might get you a bit closer ?

Answer (score 1):

In the comments, it has been suggested to use USB View, which comes with Microsoft's driver development kit.  I've tried it's German cousin [USB Device Tree Viewer](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtreeview_e.html), and it *does* show if a port has over-current.

[image: USB Device Tree Viewer shows over-current for a port]

[image: windows message "Power Surge On [USB] Hub Port"]

Comment: Hey I got the same "Device caused over-current". So how do I fix this?